# Spreadsheet - Getting values from an aggregating row to a computed column for every item in the group

Tags: google-sheets

I have this freaky question beacking my mind.

Consider the folllowing spreadsheet structure:

```
      | A   B       C       D       E
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------    
    1 | The awsome project of Foo
    2 |             
    3 | Pri Type    Issue   Estim   Subject
    4 |         
    5 | 1   Story   FA-133          The great UI feature
    6 |             FA-134  5       Do some work
    7 |             FA-135  2       Document the work
    8 |     Bug     FA-137  1       Fix the misplaced pixel
    9 |             FA-136  2       Regression test
    10|                 
    11| 2   Story   FA-153          The awsome BL computation
    12|             FA-154  5       Do some work
    13|             FA-155  2       Document the work
    14|     Bug     FA-157  1       Fix the precision trancation error
    15|     Bug     FA-129  1       Fix the wrong error code
    16|             FA-156  2       Regression test
```

**Pri**   = Priority, 
**Estim** = Estimation

Well, there's also the skill types, but lets keep things simple, right...

Now, what's the story? exactly. we're looking for the story.

### **IN SHORT**

for every record that is **not a Story** (and is not empty), I need to extract the **subject** and **priority** of the first **Story** record above it.

How can we do that on a spreadsheet?

### **Here's the full picture:**

I'm trying to help my scrum-master, who is now using a spreadsheet to communicate with our client for our grooming and planing meetings.

Now, in the beginning of every sprint, once scope is closed, he manually copies all the task lines (the ones that are not ***Story***) to memo paper notes and puts them on the board.
So far - great. We love scrum.

But: I want to automate printing of these notes. Like duhhh, We're in 2013...
For this I need a CSV or TSV string with the values for the relevant records, so I can formulate and print them.

Now, assuming I want to compute a column with the **story name** on the record of every task that says what's the story of issue task and what's the priority of this story, how would I do that on our google-spreadsheet?

I'd thank you if you skipped advises like "drag the priority to fill it for every task in the story", or "add a simple column for the story subject and fill it manually".

- First - Our client likes this spreadsheet clean and readable with no repetitive information, and we try to fit to his needs. So - hidden columns is half of the answer. Not all.
- Second - During the planning tasks are moved between stories when their priorities change, so its getting uncomfortable.

The idea is to **automate mundane work**, not to work for the computer...

If I could compute these values using a formula - it would be awsome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've spent quite a lot of hour with this, but finally got a solution which works - although not the prettiest one.

I've created a spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KdxYCvNHekAd3pXOhHftSzAzMXS9HqoOCtFoxXocCM/edit?usp=sharing - Take a look at it, I've tried to simulate the situation as close as specified. I'm going to try to explain what I've messed up :)

First I added two columns (F,G) where we are going to compute the results. The key function is pretty ugly, let's take a look at it through an example - let's have a closer look at cell F15, in which you can find the following function:

```
=if(and(B15<>"",B15<>"Story"),index(A:E,row(B15)+MAX(arrayformula(if((arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))>0,-99999999,arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15)))),1),"")
```

Pretty ugly, I admit, but maybe I can explain. (Also, in the spreadsheet I added some extra columns, H to L, in which I explain step by step the functions I use - see the numbered lists below)

First, we do a quick condition (IF) and check that the Type of the issue should not be empty or Story: `if(and(B15<>"",B15<>"Story")` - If that's TRUE, we do some magic (explained later), if FALSE, we write an empty string to this cell - `),"")` - at the very end of the big ugly function.

Now, here comes the magic. Logically it looks like:

1. Find the issue numbers for the Story-type issues.
2. Find which row numbers these issues have
3. Compute how far these rows are from "our row" (in the example, its the row 15, remember?)
4. Select the row which is the closest of our row and is before our row.
5. If we have the row number of the Story which belongs to us, we are basically done, we "only" need to navigate to that row, and get the prio and subject of that row, and copy to F15 and G15.

In the ugly function the following code snippets represent the above logic:

1. `filter(C:C,B:B="Story")` - A simple filter, which will find all the issue numbers of the Story-type issues
2. `arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))` - This will find for every issue number the exact row number.
3. `arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15)))` - A simple substraction will tell us how "far" are these rows from our row. However, we should do a little trick here, because if these result is positive it will mean that there are Stories **after** our row. But we would not like to take these to consideration, so there comes an IF, which makes sure that in these cases these options won't be picked:
   `if((arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))>0,-99999999,arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))))`
4. `MAX(arrayformula(if((arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))>0,-99999999,arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))))` - We are selecting the closest possible option. (The MAX function will select the closest NEGATIVE number to zero)
5. `index(A:E,row(B15)+MAX(arrayformula(if((arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))>0,-99999999,arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15)))),1)` - Finally, we navigate to that row with the INDEX function. The first parameter is the range, the second parameter is the row (the magic) we computed in the previous steps, and the last parameter (1) is the column number. As we need the priority here, that's why it is set to 1.

Limitations: The function assumes that every story has an issue number.

I hope it helps.

UPDATE:

If you would like to calculate for all rows which is not story but has an issue number, change the function like this:

```
=if(and(C15<>"",B15<>"Story"),index(A:E,row(B15)+MAX(arrayformula(if((arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15))>0,-99999999,arrayformula(match(filter(C:C,B:B="Story"),C:C,0))-row(B15)))),1),"")
```

(Only the first condition changed: B15 to C15)

Comment: Well, I thought that if an issue type is empty then that rwo should be empty. But it's easy to change: change the first IF condition like this: if(and(c15<>"",B15<>"Story")... All the other remain.. That way we will compute for all rows which is not a story, but has an ID. I'm going to edit the original post soon.